# directory permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, directory, group, acl

I'm currently working on a PHP server explorer, and I have to determine if a directory is empty or not readable because of insufficient permission.

My web application is running under the user `apache`, and I can see that my application can access to a folder that it cannot read according to the directory mode.

**Permissions look like this:**

```
      ls -al
drwxr-x--- 8   laura   jpGrp   4096 Aug 10 09:40 dir1
```

**Here are the content of jpGrp:**

```
      cat /etc/group | grep "jpGrp"   
jpGrp:x:501:laura,lola,gerard
```

**Here are the content of apache user :**

```
      grep apache /etc/passwd
apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin
```

**Apache is not in root groupe :**

```
      cat /etc/group | grep "root"
root:x:0:root
```

**var_dump from shell_exec("whoami") php function :**

```
string 'apache' (length=7)
```

A friend tell me to see the ACL, but there is nothing that could override the standard Unix modes.

**So: why can Apache open this directory (dir1)? (That's my question)**

---

Comment: add contents of `grep apache /etc/passwd`.  Perhaps apache has a primary group of jpGrp ?

Answer (score 1):

*> So why can apache open this directory (dir1) ?*

I haven't an answer for this, normally it should not be able to.

*> It is possible to make a group in a group ?*

No, in Linux all group members must be users.

*> Or to made a group the owner of a directory ?*

Yes, you can assign ownership of a directory to a user and a group via the command `chmod myuser:mygroup mydir`. The "group" permissions of the directory will be applied to all users which are member of that group.

Comment: ok, so no group in group (fortunately) ^^.